# Replace an element in a dataframe with 0 if it is 15% greater than or less than the element below

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with dates as the index. I'd like to zero out an element if it is significantly different (15%) than the element in the preceding date. For example:

```
df =  A      B
     1.2    2.5
      1      2
```

I'd like the new `df` to look like as follows:

```
df =  A      B
      0      0
      1      2
```

My code as of now is as follows:

```
df = df.replace(df.where(df.abs(df.divide(df.shift(-1))>.15)), 0)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
abs() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: Please show your efforts, it's not good form to simply post what you want without showing what you tried

Comment: df.replace(df.where((df.abs(df.divide(df.shift(-1)))>.15)), 0)

Comment: Edit this into your question and show why it failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
df = df.where((df.divide(df.shift(+1), df).abs() > 0.15), 0)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A  B
0  0  0
1  1  2
```